# Ввод/Вывод в Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, io

Подскажите, как в Android Studio через IO открыть файл из любой точки файловой системы?

Из своего опыта программирования на Java я знаю, что на пк, в любой операционке можно просто указать путь при создании объекта FileReader, и все будет хорошо работать. В андроиде у меня такое не работает, постоянно выбрасывается FileNotFound.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть файл из *любой* точки файловой системы без рут-прав не получится.

Android-приложение имеет доступ к двум основным файловым хранилищам:

- Internal Storage – это область памяти, которая выделяется для каждого приложения;
- External Storage – это некое внешнее хранилище (например, карта памяти).

Насколько я понял, Вас интересует второй тип. Получить доступ к корневому каталогу внешнего хранилища можно с помощью метода `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, который возвращает объект типа `File`. Получить путь к корневому хранилищу можно следующим образом:

```
String path = getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

А дальше уже можете отталкиваться от этого пути.

Comment: Я так понимаю, я буду получать ту диррректорию, которую указал при создании объекта File?

Comment: @Ник, Нет. Вы не создаете объект класса `File`, его Вам возвращает метод `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. А вообще это довольно объемная тема с множеством подводных камней, подробнее про работу с файлами можете почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.